# Parsing data from site

Tags: parsing, xml

I try parse hub titles and links from this site: https://habr.com/en/hubs/, but code returns empty list. Can not understand why.

```
Dataset[ Cases[  Import[StringJoin["https://habr.com/en/hubs/", "page", 
ToString[1]], "XMLObject"],   XMLElement[
"div", {}, {XMLElement[
  "a", {"class" -> "tm-hub__title", "href" -> link_}, 
  {___, XMLElement["span", {}, {name_}], ___}]}] :>    Association["HabName" -> name, "HabAlias" -> FileBaseName[link]],   Infinity]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cases[Import[
   StringJoin["https://habr.com/en/hubs/", "page", ToString[1]], 
   "XMLObject"], 
  XMLElement[
    "a", {OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 
      "class" -> "tm-hub__title", ___, "href" -> link_, ___]}, {___, 
     XMLElement["span", _, {name_}], ___}] :> 
   Association["HabName" -> name, "HabAlias" -> FileBaseName[link]], 
  Infinity] // Dataset
```

Cropped result:

[image]

Notes:

- `div` is removed, because found it unnecessary
- Added `___` for attributes
- Use `OrderlessPatternSequence` to cover all the permutations in attributes (could be removed in this case)

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the page probably changed. Replacing the rule inside your `Cases` command with the one below fixes it:

```
XMLElement["div", {}, 
  XMLElement["a", {___, "class" -> "tm-hub__title", "href" -> link_}, 
    {___, XMLElement["span", {}, {name_}], ___}]] :> 
  Association["HabName" -> name, "HabAlias" -> FileBaseName[link]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.